# How to send the value in python tkinter entry

Tags: python, tkinter

I am new to python and I am learning `python tkinter`
I want to enter some data in `def _ChangeDate`" and use it in other functions.
For example, print in `def _SaveDate`, but I don't know the correct way to write Request.

Thank you very much for your help

```
import os
import json
import time
import requests
import random
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from tkinter import *
import tkinter as tk
from functools import partial
from selenium.webdriver.support.wait import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By


def _SaveDate():
    # print (_ChangeDate(grp_entry))
    # print (grp_entry(_ChangeDate))
    print(grp_entry)


def _ChangeDate():
    tkWindow2 = tk.Tk()
    tkWindow2.title('1111111')
    tkWindow2.geometry('320x580')

    L1 = Label(tkWindow2, text="ac").pack()
    name_entry = tk.Entry(tkWindow2)
    name_entry.pack()

    L2 = Label(tkWindow2, text="pw").pack()
    pwd_entry = tk.Entry(tkWindow2, show='')
    pwd_entry.pack()

    L3 = Label(tkWindow2, text="grp").pack()
    grp_entry = tk.Text(tkWindow2)
    grp_entry.pack()

    # SaveDate
    button = tk.Button(tkWindow2,
                       text='save',
                       bg='green',
                       command=_SaveDate)
    button.pack()

    tkWindow2.mainloop()


_ChangeDate()
```

Comment: i dont quite understand what you are trying to do, can u please explain it a bit more

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your scope is off; your window is created in the scope of _ChangeDate(), but you are trying to use it in _SaveDate(). For both functions to use your window and the associated widgets; you must create them in the global space.

```py
from tkinter import *
import tkinter as tk


tkWindow2 = tk.Tk()
L1 = Label(tkWindow2, text="ac")
name_entry = tk.Entry(tkWindow2)
L2 = Label(tkWindow2, text="pw")
pwd_entry = tk.Entry(tkWindow2, show='')
L3 = Label(tkWindow2, text="grp")
grp_entry = tk.Text(tkWindow2)


def _SaveDate():
    # print (_ChangeDate(grp_entry))
    # print (grp_entry(_ChangeDate))
    print(grp_entry.get(1.0, END))
    # The get function will return a string of what is entered.


def _ChangeDate():
    tkWindow2.title('1111111')
    tkWindow2.geometry('320x580')

    L1.pack()
    # Using the .pack() method without saving your reference first will return
    # nothing therefore in the other code L1 would be None

    name_entry.pack()

    L2.pack()

    pwd_entry.pack()

    L3.pack()
    grp_entry.pack()

    # SaveDate
    button = tk.Button(tkWindow2,
                       text='save',
                       bg='green',
                       command=_SaveDate)
    button.pack()

    tkWindow2.mainloop()


_ChangeDate()
```

Comment: Thank you very much, it can be executed normally